# Scan LAN using NMap without specifying LAN IP

Tags: nmap

I'm very aware that you can specify an IP range and individual IPs for an NMap scan. However, I'm wondering if there's a command available to scan the LAN I'm connected to without specifying an IP.

For context, some LANs have 192.168.0.1, others have 192.168.10.1, and so on. I'm looking for a way for NMap to pick up on that automatically and run the scan based on that factor.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of the `ip a` command:

```
nmap `ip a | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1|  sed -re 's/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$//g' -e 's/[[:blank:]]+/ /g' | cut -d" " -f2`
```

It gets the ip-address with the subdomain mask and uses that as a parameter. You must add extra `nmap` parameters if you need them.

Comment: `hostname -I` would be much easier to parse, but it doesn't include the netmask

Comment: Since the OP mentions a LAN scan I do not think that `hostname -I` is sufficient as such. I must admit that I would rather type your solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifconfig` and with sample `awk` script to make the format to be IP/prefix. The command is something like:

```
ifconfig | awk -F'[ :]' -f f
```

where `f` file is:

```
 function cnt(N){
 c = 0
 for(i=0; i<8; ++i) if(and(2**i, N)) ++c
 return c
    }
function s2p(mask) {
split(mask, v, ".")
return cnt(v[1]) + cnt(v[2]) + cnt(v[3]) + cnt(v[4])
    }

  /inet/ && !/127.0.0.1/  {print $3"/"s2p($6)}
```

The `awk` functions just count the number of `1` in netmask